# Add inline .svg image in Rmarkdown

Tags: image, svg, latex, r-markdown, inline

I have used `![](https://image.png){width=25px}` for inline image but it seems not working with `.svg` image.

Is there any way that I can use this [image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Florida_in_United_States.svg) in my rmarkdown?

Comment: svg cannot be included directly in latex. There is a package called svg that aids for the inclusion of svg files. But the package calls a foreign program (inkscape) to convert svg to pdf and inkscape must present on your computer. Alternatively you can convert your file to pdf (and there are many ways to do that) and use standard pdf inclusion.

Comment: @AlainMerigot, I have tried the `svg` package before asking but not working with url `.svg` image. Converting `.svg` to `.pdf` or `.png` might be the ultimate way but just want to know if there's any other solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the R package [**rsvg**](https://github.com/jeroen/rsvg) to convert the SVG to PDF

```r
rsvg::rsvg_pdf(svg = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Florida_in_United_States.svg",
               file = "image.pdf")
```

and then include that PDF as you're used to

```
![](image.pdf){width=25px}
```

You could also convert the SVG to another image format supported by knitr using the other `rsvg::rsvg_*` converter functions, e.g. to PNG via `rsvg::rsvg_png()`. But I'd recommend to stick with vector image formats like PDF or EPS since they will print in crisp sharpness.

Note that if you install rsvg from source (likely the case on Linux), [additional system dependencies are required](https://github.com/jeroen/rsvg#installation).